# Python method to display dataframe rows with least common column string

Tags: python, class, methods

I have a dataframe with 3 columns (department, sales, region), and I want to write a method to display all rows that are from the least common region. Then I need to write another method to count the frequency of the departments that are represented in the least common region.  No idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions would be unecessary - [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) already has implementations to accomplish what you want! Suppose I had the following csv file, `test.csv`...

```
department,sales,region
sales,26,midwest
finance,45,midwest
tech,69,west
finance,43,east
hr,20,east
sales,34,east
```

If I'm understanding you correctly, I would obtain a DataFrame representing the least common region like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

counts = df['region'].value_counts()
least_common = counts[counts == counts.min()].index[0]

least_common_df = df.loc[df['region'] == least_common]
```

`least_common_df` is now:

```
  department  sales region
2       tech     69   west
```

As for obtaining the department frequency for the least common region, I'll leave that up to you. (I've already shown you how to get the frequency for region.)